# How am I supposed to read this

Tags: recurrence-relations

So we started difference equations and im having a very very hard tome wrapping my head around it, im using our assigned textbook.
How am I supposed to read 2^t(2)

Image:
https://500px.com/photo/1009285382/-image-jpg-by-mmm-aly

Comment: If you need a image for more context let me know

Comment: Yes, an image would help.

Comment: the name of the textbook would also help. With authors, and edition number

Comment: "Mathematics for Economics" by Micheal Hoy, John Livernois, Chris McKenna, Ray Rees, Thanasis Stengo. Third Edition

Comment: Looks like when they write $2^t(2)$ they just mean $2^t\times 2$...

Comment: So how does that link 2^t = 2^(t+1)? I'm struggling to see the relation

Comment: They are trying to verify that $y_t=2^t$ satisfies the difference equation. It indeed does, because $y_{t+1}=2^{t+1}=2\cdot 2^t=2y_t$.

Comment: They are not equal without the following factor of $2$.  The paragraph is trying to justify that $2^t$ satisfies the recurrence.

Comment: Quick question...wouldn't that make it 4yt? ...Apologies if my questions are beyond dumb but this topic is so jarring to me

Comment: The text you show says "writing $2^{t+1}$ as $2^t(2)$", which clearly means that $2^{t+1}$ is the same as $2^t$ times $2$.  In other words, multiplying $t+1$ copies of $2$ gives the same result as multiplying $t$ copies times one more copy of $2$.  Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are simply saying that $2^{t+1}$ is the same as writing $ 2^{t}2$. Utilizing the exponent rules (don't know how it's really phrased in english) where $$a^{b+c} = a^{b}a^{c}.$$
Hope this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

The whole sentence, which it would have helped a lot if you quoted it, says
But $2^{t+1}=2^t(2)$.  It is just multiplication, as in $2^{t+1}=2^t \cdot 2$

Comment: Apologizes, Will do next time..what's the relation then?